# Include negative value in sum/total value in stacked bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a stacked bar chart that looks like this.[image]

However, I'm trying to include the negative values (ninth column in the `datatable`) into the total value on the stacked bar chart so that in the end some of the total values are negative like this:

[image].

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
        show sum on top/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \node[
                    at={(normalized axis cs:%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                    },
                    anchor=south,
                ]
                {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
 \pgfplotstableread{
Year    OneCol  SecCol  ThirdCol ForthCol FifthCol SixthCol SeventhCol EigthCol NinthCol TenthCol EleventhCol
2005    0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 -2.5    0.0 0.3  
2006    0.3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 -2.5    0.0 0.3
2007    0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 -2.1    0.0 0.8
2008    1.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.6 0.0 0.0 -1.8    0.0 1.9
2009    0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 -2.1    0.0 0.9
2010    3.9 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 -1.4    0.0 5.6
2011    0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 -1.9    -0.1 0.8
2012    11.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 -1.0   0.0 13.7
2013    0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 -2.6    0.0 0.2
}\datatable

\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=0.9*\textwidth,
      bar width=0.26cm,
      tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,font=\footnotesize},
      stack negative=on previous,
      ybar stacked,
      bar width=1em,
      ymin=-10,
      axis on top,
      ymax=30,
      ymajorgrids = true,
      enlarge x limits={true, abs value=0.75},
      height=8cm,
      nodes near coords={},
      legend style={
      at={(1.1,0.5)},
      anchor=west,
      draw=none },
      xtick=data,
      xticklabels={GWP,ODP,POCP, AP, EP(T), EP(FW), EP(M), ADP, CED}
      ]
      \addplot [fill=cyan!70,draw=black!70] table [y index=1] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=green!90,draw=black!70] table [y index=2] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=teal!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=3] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=violet!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=4] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=lime!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=5] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=magenta!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=6] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=red!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=7] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=blue!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=8] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=yellow!90,draw=black!70] table [y index=9] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=purple!90,draw=black!70] table [y index=10] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=olive!90,draw=black!70,show sum on top] table [y index=11] {\datatable};
  \legend{Facade,Column,Core,Drywall,Foundation,Roof,Slab,Window,Operation,Disposal,Replacement}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Impacts by category relative to baseline building with conventional building envelope}
\label{relative}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I want the total value on top of each bar to include the negative values because obviously the negative values in the ninth column are ignored in the sum of every bar. (You can see the total values in the two pictures are different - due to the exclusion of negative values in the first pic)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! May I ask you to append this to your question? Then others having similar issues can more easily understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that your keys are not ordered appropriately. You need to move `stack negative=on previous` after `ybar stacked`. And I also took the liberty to make the anchors depend on the sign of the coordinates such that they will be below the bars (rather than interfere) for negative y values.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
        show sum on top/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \path let \p1=($(normalized axis cs:%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                            -(normalized axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},0)$)
                in node[
                    at={(normalized axis cs:%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                    },
                    anchor={-90*sign(\y1)},yshift={sign(\y1)*2pt}
                ]
                {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
 \pgfplotstableread{
Year    OneCol  SecCol  ThirdCol ForthCol FifthCol SixthCol SeventhCol EigthCol NinthCol TenthCol EleventhCol
2005    0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 -2.5    0.0 0.3  
2006    0.3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 -2.5    0.0 0.3
2007    0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 -2.1    0.0 0.8
2008    1.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.6 0.0 0.0 -1.8    0.0 1.9
2009    0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 -2.1    0.0 0.9
2010    3.9 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 -1.4    0.0 5.6
2011    0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 -1.9    -0.1 0.8
2012    11.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 -1.0   0.0 13.7
2013    0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 -2.6    0.0 0.2
}\datatable

\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=0.9*\textwidth,
      bar width=0.26cm,
      tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,font=\footnotesize},
      ybar stacked,
      stack negative=on previous, %<- moved down
      bar width=1em,
      ymin=-10,
      axis on top,
      ymax=30,
      ymajorgrids = true,
      enlarge x limits={true, abs value=0.75},
      height=8cm,
      nodes near coords={},
      legend style={
      at={(1.1,0.5)},
      anchor=west,
      draw=none },
      xtick=data,
      xticklabels={GWP,ODP,POCP, AP, EP(T), EP(FW), EP(M), ADP, CED}
      ]
      \addplot [fill=cyan!70,draw=black!70] table [y index=1] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=green!90,draw=black!70] table [y index=2] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=teal!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=3] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=violet!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=4] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=lime!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=5] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=magenta!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=6] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=red!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=7] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=blue!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=8] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=yellow!90,draw=black!70] table [y index=9] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=purple!90,draw=black!70] table [y index=10] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=olive!90,draw=black!70,show sum on top] table [y index=11] {\datatable};
  \legend{Facade,Column,Core,Drywall,Foundation,Roof,Slab,Window,Operation,Disposal,Replacement}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Impacts by category relative to baseline building with conventional building envelope}
\label{relative}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]